# Localhost and Webhost errors

Tags: javascript

This code works on online compilers as well as stackoverflow but why not on my web host as well as localhost.

```
<html>
    <head><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.radiogroup').on('change', function() {
      $('#amount').val( this.value );
    });</script></head>
    <body>
    <input type="radio" name="radiogroup" class="radiogroup" value="5" />
    <input type="radio" name="radiogroup" class="radiogroup" value="10" />
    <input type="radio" name="radiogroup" class="radiogroup" value="15" />
    <input type="radio" name="radiogroup" class="radiogroup" value="20" />
    <br /><br />
    <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" /></body>
    </html>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you describe the problem you are having? Since it works in online compilers.

Comment: radio buttons can be made on and off but no text appears in the text. code is made in such a way that the text box changes its value as per the radio button

Comment: @Joel i added a screen shot too

Comment: Check the browser's console for possible errors.

Comment: how to check them?

Answer (score 0):

Your head and body tags are intermingled. I've updated it to correctly show the head and body sections.

```
<html>
 <head>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $('.radiogroup').on('change', function() {
        $('#amount').val( this.value );
      });
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <input type="radio" name="radiogroup" class="radiogroup" value="5" />
  <input type="radio" name="radiogroup" class="radiogroup" value="10" />
  <input type="radio" name="radiogroup" class="radiogroup" value="15" />
  <input type="radio" name="radiogroup" class="radiogroup" value="20" />
  <br /><br />
  <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" />
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: no they got intermingled while posting the question, same problem persists

Answer (score 0):

Your head and body tags are intermingled and if u want to use html5 you don't need to define the script-type, and you don't have to declare not-closed-tags with trailing backslash. 
If you want to use an earlier version of html use the type. 
If you want to use xhtml you have to use trailing backslashes for not-closed-tags.

Edit: I figured out, that your code is triggered before the Elements are rendered, so you try to add a event-handler to Elements that are not present at that time. Adding $(function() {}); around your code will force jQuery to run the code after document-ready event is triggered.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
          $(function() {
            $('.radiogroup').on('change', function() {
              $('#amount').val(this.value);
            });
           });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="radio" name="radiogroup" class="radiogroup" value="5">
        <input type="radio" name="radiogroup" class="radiogroup" value="10">
        <input type="radio" name="radiogroup" class="radiogroup" value="15">
        <input type="radio" name="radiogroup" class="radiogroup" value="20">
        <br><br>
        <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: no they got intermingled while posting the question, same problem persists

Comment: even the code you provide didn't worked. same problem textbox remains empty

Answer (score 0):

Your Javascript is running too early, before any HTML elements (your radio buttons) are present. Your selector `$('.radiogroup')` then does not find anything, and nothing happens when you click the radio buttons.

Either move your Javascript at the end before the `</body>` closing tag or wrap your code in jQuery's [`.ready`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.radiogroup').on('change', function() {
    $('#amount').val( this.value );
  });
})
```

Comment: you fixed it champ!